# Cannot assign locationManager() function to DispatchQueue.main.async { * }

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting an error while trying to assign function locationManager() in the DispatchQueue.main.async {}, ill provide whole code and specific pic of error for more clarity --> [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORylh.png)

I got most of the code from SeanAllen on yt since I am new to swift and learning everyday so this code isn't my logic, and the function fetchAndReloadData() is my functionalists I created to get the lat and long from the API assigning to the correct car id since it will track Vehicles on map (car tracking app)

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

var globalVechicle = [Vehicles]()
var id = "6438367CC43848B497FE4604AF465D6A"

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let regionInMeters: Double = 10000

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

@IBAction func changeMapType(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        mapView.mapType = .standard
    }else {
        mapView.mapType = .satellite
    }
    
}


@IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkLocationServices()
}


func setupLocationManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
}


func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
    if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}


func checkLocationServices() {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        setupLocationManager()
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    } else {
        // show alert they have to turn it on
    }
}


func checkLocationAuthorization() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        centerViewOnUserLocation()
        fetchAndReloadData()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    case .denied:
        // show alert instructing them how to turn on the permissions
        break
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .restricted:
        // Show an alert letting them know what's up
        break
    case .authorizedAlways:
        break
    @unknown default:
        print("Error")
    }
}
}


extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func fetchAndReloadData(){
    APICaller.shared.getVehicles(for: id) {[weak self] (result) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let vehicle):
            self.globalVechicle = vehicle
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.locationManager()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let lattitude = globalVechicle[0].Latitude ,let longitude = globalVechicle[0].Longitude else { return }
    let carLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lattitude , longitude: longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: carLocation, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    mapView.delegate = self
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    checkLocationAuthorization()
}
}
```

Comment: You don't have `func locationManager()`, that's why there is the error. You have a variable named `locationManager`, not a function/method. You might want to call `self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`or `self.checkLocationAuthorization()` instead?

Comment: Thanks a Lott I tried the self.checkLocationAuthorization() , but how can I make the blue dot show up now mate since its coming from the function centerViewOnUserLocation()

Comment: To get the blue dot on a map view, just set the `showsUserLocation` property to `true`. As long as you have location permission the mapView does the reset.

Comment: @Paulw11 but its not user location tracker , its app about tracking other cars and that's why I need the blue dot to show on the vehicles on map not current user logged in

Comment: Then you will need to add an annotation to the map. This is not (normally) a "blue dot"